# Como salvar Cookies de um site remoto com cURL?

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou com dificuldades em salvar e ler os cookies de um site remoto que estou a abrir com cURL:

```
            $cr = curl_init($this->_URL);
            curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent );           
            curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');   
            $html = curl_exec($cr); 
            curl_close($cr);
```

Já tentei `COOKIEJAR` e etc, mas não funciona!

O site que estou abrindo em cURL, salva cookies quando clicamos em um determinado valor, este cookie mais tarde é lido por outro arquivo do site, testei com o proxy do projeto do Glype, e funciona perfeitamente, ele salva o cookie, mesmo eu abrindo o site pelo meu `cURL` e acessando o arquivo que ler os cookies pelo proxy do glype que está no mesmo servidor, ele acha os cookies, mas meu cURL não acha!

Como eu salvo e leio posteriormente os cookies de um site remoto usando cURL?

Comment: De acordo com esse tópico (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295586/why-php-curl-does-not-save-cookie-in-my-cookiefile) Você precisa usar o caminho absoluto para salvar um cookie. `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie_file) );`

Comment: ja tentou capturar pelo header? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`

Comment: Já tentei sim, mas não funciona!
não sei o que pode está errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque o cURL por HttpRequest http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.httprequest.php

É orientado a objeto e bem melhor documentado, além de mais fácil de usar.